# how to get ip address of client computer connected to node.js server by ajax(xmlhttprequest)

Tags: ajax, node.js, ip

i am trying to get ip address of my client computer,

```
 console.log("ipaddress : "+req.headers['x-forwarded-for']);
```

but the result is

```
   ipaddress : undefined
```

Comment: Are you using express or something? What is your express proxy setting? x-forwarded-for is taking addresses from proxy - if you're doing this on a local dev computer, without nginx in front of Node.js, you won't have a x-forwarded-for at all.

Comment: I am not using express, my client side there is a simple javascript file and on server side a node js file which create a server and serves the client requests.